# Set offset shape as background on title

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

Basically I want to have a title and then behind it a square thats offset. I've tried to do this by positioning absolute my square and then putting behind the title but when I resize the page it goes off position.

[image]

I'm trying to achive the shape behind the title in the image example.

What I tried:

```css
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(25, 94, 76);
  top: 43vh;
  left: 28vw;
  z-index: -1;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;  /*Half width*/
  top: 50%;  /*Half height*/                 translateY(-50%);  
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%)   
                     translateY(-50%);  
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  Resize the page to see the shape go off center
</div>

<div class="shape"></div>
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/PhoenixBeatsYT/pen/XWjZLgB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the shape *inside* your text div then adjust to to the top and left.

Minor adjustments are probably necessary for perfect alignment.

```css
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(25, 94, 76);
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  Resize the page to see the shape go off center
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```